# Checking if user signed in before react native

Tags: javascript, authentication, react-native

In my react native app I save the user information securely on the key chain, so that after they have logged in once, I save the information and then the next time the user comes, the information is already there and so the user won't need to log in.

The issue is that I do the check in componentDidMount, and then if the user has never logged in before or logged out in their last visit I redirect them to the loginScreen like so:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    //Need to check if they've signed in before by checking the USER_INFO.
    SecureStore.getItemAsync("USER_INFO").then(response => {
        //Have they signed in before?
        if (response !== undefined) {
          //yes.
          //continue with app stuff.
        }
        else {
          //Not logged in before need to go to login.
          const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
              NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login', params: this.props.navigation.state.params }),
            ]
          });
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);

        }
    });

}
```

The problem is that I get a warning that 'Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.'. Which makes sense because I am redirecting before the screen has rendered, but then the question is, where should I perform these checks?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that you are using react-navigation. I have done the same thing that you are trying to accomplish but in a different way.

To simplify I have three screens in a navigator

```
// Navigator.js
export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: SplashView },
  Login: { screen: LoginView },
  RootDrawer: { screen: RootDrawer }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Splash'
});
```

And then in my SplashView (which is my starting point) I authenticate the user in its constructor. And while it is authenticating the user, the SplashView is simply rendering a Text that says "Splash Screen" but could obviously be anything.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.authenticateSession();
}

authenticateSession() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    dispatch(storeGetAccount())
      .then(() => {
        navigation.dispatch(navigateToAccountView(true));
      })
      .catch(() => {
        navigation.dispatch(navigateToLoginView());
      });
}
```

The functions `navigateToAccountView()` `and navigateToLoginView()` are just so I can use them at other places but the `navigateToLoginView()` looks like this

```
export function navigateToLoginView() {
  return NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })
    ]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually and as far as I know, the best way to handle this kind of checks is by wrapping your component by some HOC[(High Order Component)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) Doing your logic there, and depending if the user passes the checks you can throw a redirection to login page or load the user data and keep forward rendering your component.

This is a good practice so you can create a `withAuth()` HOC that will wrap the components or the parts of your app that can only be accessed by authenticated users. And you will have a component that is highly reusable.

So you will export your "protected component" like this:

`export default withAuth(myComponent)`

performing the logic in the `withAuth` HOC instead of in you component.